# Django query sort by all satisfying a condition and then all the others

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models `City` and `Contact`.

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name_surname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    preference = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=PREFERENCE)
    city = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

Given a city "A" I am trying to query my DB to get a list of

- All contacts that have "A" as a city order by preference
- And after that all contacts that don't have "A" as a city order by preference

So basically if my Contact table (name, city, preference) had something like

- Tom,NY,2
- John, LA, 5
- Mike, NY, 1
- Richard, SF, 4

and the city I am considering is NY, the query would return:

- Mike, NY, 1
- Tom,NY,2
- Richard, SF, 4
- John, LA, 5

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
qs1 = Contact.objects.filter(city__name="NY")
qs2 = Contact.objects.exclude(city__name="NY").order_by("city")

qs1.union(qs2, all=True)
```

It's possible you wont need `all=True`. I needed it for my test.

[Docs on `union()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


Contact.objects.annotate(
    has_ny=Exists(
        City.objects.filter(name='NY', contact=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
).order_by('-has_ny', 'preference')
```

Comment: This one gives me `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'contact_set' into field. Choices are: address, callsheet, contact, id, jobposition, jobproject, lat, long, name, owner, owner_id, state`. What is `contact_set=OuterRef('pk')` supposed to be/do?

Comment: It should be the related name of contact from city. Try to use `contact`

Comment: Still error. If I remove it completely it works though. What's the role of that filter?

Comment: It is to check if a contact has any city that is named `NY` and annotate a boolean flag. Whats the new error?

Comment: It’s the same of before, it doesn’t recognize the keyword

Comment: Can you share the error when you use `contact=OuterRef('pk')`?

Comment: It's the same of above with the different key basically--> `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'contact' into field. Choices are: address, callsheet, contact, id, jobposition, jobproject, lat, long, name, owner, owner_id, state. What is contact=OuterRef('pk')`

Comment: I tried this out on my end and works fine. Can you try using `contact__pk=OuterRef('pk'))`.

Comment: `contact=OuterRef('pk')` is to reference the contact in the city filter from the outer queryset